Emscripten for older browsers
I need to run Emscripten on a very old browser (Chrome 47), but the latest version of Emscripten does not support such an old browser.
What is the latest version of Emscripten that still supports Chrome 47?
The C++ code I tried to run with:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

https://i.sstatic.net/93ne0.png

EmScripten can compile code directly to JS rather than WebAssembly(the default) to be run in older browsers without WebAssembly support.  If your target is older than Chrome 57, it won't have WASM support.  try something like emcc [..args..] -sWASM=0.  see https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/WebAssembly.html#setup

I did as you said. But it didn't help, I attached a screenshot of the error to the question.

Be wary of using old browser versions, as those may have unpatched vulnerabilities.

why are you needing to target an old browser?

I'm making a web program for my old TV, it just has chrome 47 version
